# How to exclude some characters from a string in java?

Tags: java, android

**EDITED**

I have a string like:

**`" abc@1asdf.net , efg@askdhfk.net , hig@qlewxcvxcvzxcvz.net , klm@qw.net , "`**

i want to exclude **hig@qlewxcvxcvzxcvz.net**. The resulting string should be :

**`" abc@1asdf.net , efg@askdhfk.net , klm@qw.net , "`**

Plz, can anyone guide me for solution. I have tried using **`substring`** but couldn't.

I dnt know the length

My Try :

```
mystr.substring(mystr.indexOf("hig"), mystr.indexOf(","));
```

Comment: Post the code you tried at least!!

Comment: Try `string.replace`

Comment: unclear. What you want to remove is `hig@123.net` but you don't know what is after `@`. In you exemple, it's always `123.net`

Comment: According to your example, you don't want to remove all `hig@123.net` substrings, but all `hig@123.net` entries from a comma separated list. Not the same thing. What to do with `xxhig@123.netxx` for instance ?

Comment: i want to remove **hig@qlewxcvxcvzxcvz.net ,** from the whole string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **String java.lang.String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)**

The code is here:

```
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringTest stringTest = new StringTest();
        stringTest.test();
    }

    public void test(){
        String s1 = " abc@123.net , efg@123.net , hig@123.net , klm@123.net , ";
        String s2 = "hig@123.net , ";
        String s3 = s1.replace(s2, "");
        System.out.println(s3);
    }   
}
```

Hope that it will help you.

The effect is **abc@123.net , efg@123.net , klm@123.net ,**

Answer (score 1):

Try Using replaceAll method of String

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("hig@123.net ,?", ""));//will work even if you dont have comma at the end of the string.
//if you are sure that every String has " ," then consider using replace("hig@123.net ,", "");
```

Comment: Thnx alot, small and precise answer

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = " abc@123.net , efg@123.net , hig@123.net , klm@123.net , ";
    String findStr = "hig@123.net";
    if(str.contains(findStr)){
        str = str.replace(findStr, "");
    }
```

I hope it will helpful to you.
Thank's